# Importing text from one HTML and inserting it into another with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a latest news style section on the home page of the site i'm designing, where I would like to take the heading from my article page and use it as the heading in my latest news section on my home page, the latest news section on my home page looks like this:

```
<body onload="insertText()">
<section class="latest">
                <h1 class="latesth" id="test"> Latest News: </h1>

                        <section class="title" onclick="changeImagea()">
                            <h3 id="h1" > Mcilroy Wins US Open </h3>
                            <p> He wins by three shots in horrendous condition, <u>click here</u> to read more </p>
                        </section>

                        <section class="title" onclick="changeImageb()">
                            <h3> Tiger Wins Masters </h3>
                            <p> He wins by three shots in horrendous condition, <u>click here</u> to read more </p>
                        </section>

                        <section class="titlebottom" onclick="changeImagec()">
                            <h3> Mcilroy Wins US Open </h3>
                            <p> He wins by three shots in horrendous condition, <u>click here</u> to read more </p>
                        </section>
                </section>
```

my javascript for doing this so far looks like this and its in an external javascript file:

```
 function insertText () {
    var x = document.getElementById('ahead').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = x;
    }
```

and finally the text in the article.php page id like to grab and insert into the home page looks like this:

```
<section>
<h1 id="ahead"> hello </h1>
</section>
```

Thank you for your help, hope i was clear.

Comment: im trying to insert the heading from the article on the 6th line of the html, in the <h3 id ="h1" > tag?

Comment: You're clear on what you want to do. You're not clear on what the question is. The code as you show it will work fine as long as the elements exist when the code runs, and as long as your `insertText` function is global.

Comment: If this is a PHP / database driven site would it not be easier to just pull the data from the same source as the article page? If these are separate pages then to do it in JS you'll need to jump through hoops

Comment: the code works when both ids your accessing are in the same html page but it doesnt work when the "ahead" id is in a seperate html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using jQuery for this one, it will save you tons of time and issues.

If the #ahead element is in another page you could do something like:

```
$('h1').load('/foo #ahead');
```